# How do I pass array value in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, cesiumjs

This is for a menu. `jArray4[i]` is what appears on the button.
No matter what is selected  `data: {'action': ''+jArray4[i]+''}`,
results in the last button being selected. I am new to Jquery so I don't know how to properly pass the correctly selected button.

```
var object = {   
  text : ''+(jArray4[i]) +'',
  onselect : function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'ajaxreturn.php',
      data: {'action': ''+jArray4[i]+''},
      success: function(json)
      {
        alert(json.first);
      }
    });        
  }
};
options.push(object);
Sandcastle.addToolbarMenu(options);
```

Comment: depends on how you're assigning `i`. And you don't need the single quotes `''`

Comment: Can you tell us what your `jArray4` looks like?

Comment: jArray4 looks like [ "'s-Hertogenbosch,Netherlands", "Aalborg,Denmark", "Aarau,Switzerland", "Aba,Nigeria", "Abadan,Iran", "Abadan,Iraq", "Abakan,Russia", "Abbotsford,Canada", "Abeokuta,Nigeria", "Aberdeen,United Kingdom", 2063 more… ]

Comment: Its working now, the answer was "let i=0" instead of "var i=0"